# How to refer pyspark.dbutils when developing code on local machine

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I'm new to Pyspark and asking question for best design pattern/practice:

I'm developing a library that should run both, on local machine and on Databricks.

Currently working on loading secrets. If code runs on databricks, I should load secrets using `dbutils.secrets.get` while if code runs on local machine, `dotenv.load_dotenv`.

Question:
How can I create/refer to `dbutils` variable (which is readily provided in databricks instance)? pyspark doesnt have such module... even if I import `SparkSession` I still need `DBUtils` which is not found on pyspark local installation.

my current solution: if identify that code runs on Databricks, I create `dbutils` with:

```
dbutils = globals()['dbutils']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow the approach described in [documentation for databricks-connect](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#access-dbutils) - wrap instantiation of `dbutils` into a function call that will behave differently depending on if you're on Databricks or not:

```py
def get_secret(....):
  if spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.service.client.enabled") == "true":
    from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils
    return DBUtils(spark).secrets.get(....)
  else:
    get local secret
```